# direct web remoting asynchronous issue

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dwr

I am using the direct web remoting library to do some ajax calls in my application.  I am having a problem that I think comes down to a delayed response from the service call.  Below is part of my code that I think is having the problem.  The problem is in getDefaultReviewerTypeCode, the return variable isn't set in the call back till after other "stuff" processes.  Is there a way to tell DWR to wait for a response before it continues processing the java script?

```
function makeProtocolReviewerTypesDropDown(reviewerTypes, reviewerIndex) {
var defaultReviewerType = getDefaultReviewerTypeCode();

...
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.setAttribute("value", "");
if (defaultReviewerType == '') {
    option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
}

...

for (var i = 0; i < reviewerTypes.length; i += 2) {
    var reviewerType = reviewerTypes[i].replace(/^\t*/, '');
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute("value", reviewerType);
    if (defaultReviewerType == reviewerType) {
        option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
    option.text = reviewerTypes[i+1];
    addSelectOption(selectElement, option);
}

return selectElement;
}

function getDefaultReviewerTypeCode() {
var defaultReviewTyper;
var dwrReply = {
        callback:function(data) {
            if ( data != null ) {   
                defaultReviewTyper = data;
            } else {
                defaultReviewTyper = '';
            }
        }
};
IacucProtocolActionAjaxService.getDefaultCommitteeReviewTypeCode(dwrReply);
return defaultReviewTyper;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to encapsulate all code that follows the DWR call into a separate method, and call that from the DWR callback. That way, your code that depends on the DWR results is guaranteed to be called only after DWR returns.

Comment: ah, great idea, will give this a try in the morning